# restoring a deleted file, returning an error

Tags: data-recovery, delete, extundelete

I've had the bad luck of removing a file that was not yet added to a git repository.

I'm trying to recover it with this code:

```
mount -o remount, ro /dev/sda1 # to remount in read only mode.
extundelete --restore-file path/to/file /dev/sda1 #restore in same partition
mount -o remount, rw /dev/sda1 #put partition back in write mode.
```

I'm doing that while logged on a tty.

But I get an error saying `/dev/sda1 is unmounted or bad option`.

If I run lsblk I get sda and the partitions sda1 to sda4, where sda1 is the /home. So I'm confused on how to proceed.

Any help?

Comment: Do you really have a space after the comma in the `mount` commands, or is that a typo?

Comment: @AndyDalton thanks. Now I get `mount point busy`